# Job DSL Restrict jobs to selected nodes

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am struggling to restrict Jenkins job to specific nodes using Job DSL plugin.

I tried something like :

```
job("campaign") {
    parameters {
     stringParam("ARTIFACT_NUMBER", "","")
     nodeParam('TEST_HOST') {
         defaultNodes(["Slave"])
     }
    }
    steps {
        shell('''#!/bin/bash
ARTIFACT_DIR=daily_${ARTIFACT_NUMBER}
echo ${ARTIFACT_DIR}
            ''')
    }
}
```

but no success. Basically, I want to set the property `Restrict where this project can run` through Job DSL plugin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `label` method sets the `Restrict where this project can run` on job level:

```
job('example') {
    label('agentA agentB')
}
```

See the API viewer for details: https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-label